# Is it possible to show dynamic data in real time in an html with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, telegram-bot

I am developing with spring boot in Intellij, implement a service that is a class of the telegram api that receives messages through a bot, what I would like to do is show those messages that arrive in real time in a datatable and as they arrive the message is seen in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to build an interactive web application using Web Sockets.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

This establishes a continuous 2-way connection allowing client-side javascript to recieve updates and dynamically update the webpage.

Edit:

Here is a link to a full example project.

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket